# Getting single result from Simple XML Array

Tags: php, xml

Ok i am using a simple XML function to get some information from a remote database, this works fine, however it returns all of the information in an xml format, and what i want to do is just show the results of one field, so for example below is the result i want to display

```
 <product id="9" name="Computer screwdriver" datasheet="" packshot=""/>
```

and below is my code

```
$file = 'http://computers.mysite.co.uk/vrm.xml?apikey=**********&vid=Check&vrm='.$reg;
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file))
 exit('Failed to open '.$file);
 print_r($id);
```

UPDATE

ok so i have now changed my code to this:

```
 $data  = simplexml_load_file("http://test.mysite.co.uk/test.xml?   apikey=********&vid=app&vrm='.$reg;");

 print $data->computers->computer->products->product->name;
```

The xml structure is here:

```
<computers sid="1234">
  <computer id="253406" name="computer name)" model_group="Microsofth" start_year="2005" end_year="2009">
    <system id="969623" capacity="3.4"/>
      <developer id="64" name="intel"/>
      <machine id="8" name="P" etype="P"/>
    <products>
      <product id="9" name="computer screwdriver" datasheet="" packshot=""/>
      <product id="16" name="Screwdriver Crosshead" datasheet="" packshot=""/>
    </products>
  </computer>
 </computers
```

What i want to do is to return the name of the product in the first line of products only, in this case id = 9.

At the moment the way the code isn't showing any results though if i change it to show all results it does, so the problem is just trying to filter that one result out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _"so for example below is the result i want to display"_ Where is the result ?

Comment: I think the point is to load all roots and then get the preferred node from them. I've never heard about just getting single node by SimpleXML.

Answer (score 0):

$data->xpath("you_selector")
and don't forget 
header("Content-Type:text/xml");

Comment: sorry what do you mean by Xpath("you_Selector) I am a newbie and kind of just thumbling through trying to learn.